# Calling method with a button in a loop

Tags: java, button, javafx, increment

I have created a gridPane called gPaneCenter which is designed to create a table. When I add an item to the grid it will call the mehtod addRow(), please see below:

```
public static void addRow() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    Label prodDes = new Label(String.valueOf(Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).getProduct().getDescription()));
    Label prodPrice = new Label(String.valueOf(Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).getProduct().getUnitPrice()));
    Label prodQuant = new Label(String.valueOf(Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).getQuantity()));
    Label prodCost = new Label(String.valueOf(Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).getCost()));

    HBox quantityChanger = new HBox();
    Button decreaseQuantBut = new Button("-");
    Button increaseQuantBut = new Button("+");


    decreaseQuantBut.setOnAction(e -> Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).decreaseQuantity());
    increaseQuantBut.setOnAction(e -> Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(i).increaseQuantity());

    quantityChanger.getChildren().addAll(decreaseQuantBut,prodQuant,increaseQuantBut);

    View.gPaneCenter.addRow(l, prodDes,prodPrice,quantityChanger,prodCost);
    l++;
    i++;
}
```

'i' and 'l' are declared at the start:

```
static int i = 0;
static int l = 1;
```

Which produces the following GUI when an item is added:

[image]

When I click the "-" button or "+" button I would like to decrease the quantity and increase the quantity respectively however I get the following error when I click either button:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at model.Cart.getOrder(Cart.java:59)
```

Which suggests it cannot find order however it can successfully find the order to print the following: prodDes, prodPrice and prodQuant.

Method of called the order in class Cart, this is also (Cart.java.59):

```
    public Order getOrder(int i) {
    return contents.get(i);
}
```

Method of increasing and decreasing the quantity in class Order:

```
    public void increaseQuantity() {
    quantity++;
}

public void decreaseQuantity() {
    quantity--;
}
```

The methods for used for getting the prodQuant and prodCost (prodDes and prodUnitPrice are through getProduct() ):

```
    public int getCost() {
    return quantity * item.getUnitPrice();
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return item;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: @c0der How to increase and decrease the quantity due to me getting errors as stated above midway down the question? The error is

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at model.Cart.getOrder(Cart.java:59)**

Comment: Why are you doing i++ in the end of the code segment? You move it from 0 to 1, which is the reason for the indexOutOfBounds.

Comment: @Assafs This is to increment 'i' so that I can then call the next order in the array which would be '1' then again for the next product so that it would print all part of the order relating to i.

Comment: I would suggest either incrementing I just before the next order, or doing setOnAction using i-1.

Comment: For future posts and more efficient help consider posting [mcve]

Comment: @C0der Okay thank you will keep this in mind for a future post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `i` to identify a certain row, but the value of `i` changes when you add more rows.

```
public static void addRow() {   
    int rowNum = i; //solution: a local variable to keep current i value  
     .....
    decreaseQuantBut.setOnAction(e -> Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(rowNum).decreaseQuantity());
    increaseQuantBut.setOnAction(e -> Controller.shoppingCart.getOrder(rowNum).increaseQuantity());
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a possible way of getting the set quantity methods without calling for i so this does no occur?

Comment: The answer includes a proposed solution. I added a comment to clarify.